prevent scrollbar auto-scrolling without fixed position
i have a child that has a scrollbar that inherits it's w/h from its parent.whenever the parent resizes due to viewport size, the child's scrollbar resizes which causes it to auto scroll, how can i fix this without setting fixed w/h?
    <section class="displaySection">
        <button class="leftArrow" id="prev" onclick="moveCarousle(this)">&#8656</button>     
        <button class="rightArrow" id="next" onclick="moveCarousle(this)">&#8656</button>
        <div class="displayCase">
            <div class="boxOfCandles"></div>
            <div class="medicine"></div>
            <div class="sports"></div>
            <div class="pets"></div>
            <div class="books"></div>
        </div>
    </section>

.displayCase {
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
.displaySection {
    width: 60vw;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 5pc;
    height: 40vw;
    border: 1px solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

}

               .       


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

I don't quite understand which one is child you talk about? displayCase? Add more code to show the problem and use code snipped so we cen see effect of the code directly in your post.
